# Callback function with Mongo-trigger

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, callback

I am working with `mongodb`, `nodejs`, `socket.io` project. I want to detect collection changes and send to my client page through `socket.io`. So I used `mongo-trigger` library to trigger events. Following is my code.

```
watcher.watch('test.students', function(event) {

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

        socket.emit('mongodata',event);
    });

});
```

Problem is how can I implement as a callback function because I cannot get the `event` value to emit via socket.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by changing the approach. Following code emits mongo event data.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    watcher.watch('test.students', function(event) {
        socket.emit('mongodata', event);

    });
});
```